# Shoulder Mobility: Standing and Lying Dislocation Exercise Difference

Tags: exercise, training, flexibility, back, mobility

Whats the difference between the Standing Stick shoulder mobility exercise,  standing up and lying down? Do they exercise different muscle groups? Trying to understand the difference between doing the two.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just doing them as a stretching/mobility exercise, then there's no difference, as the range of motion through which your shoulders move is identical in both exercises.

However [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBbUtlZN0SI) explains that the black and red thing in the middle of the stick is a weight, intended to turn the exercise into a strength exercise. In that case, doing it standing means the weight makes if harder to raise the stick from in front of you to above your shoulders, working the anterior deltoids, whereas when doing it lying the weight makes it harder to bring the bar from having your arms outstretches overhead to behind the back, working the posterior deltoids.

That said, this is a pretty terrible strength exercise (difficult to add significant loading to and highly unlikely to be used in a progressively loaded manner) and it's probably best to just stick to whichever version of the unweighted mobility exercise you prefer, if increased shoulder mobility is your goal.

Comment: what is an alternative method to do progressions? thats what I am trying to figure out, thanks !

Comment: @mattsmith5 do you mean for progressing strength, or flexibility?

Comment: progression in flexibility